Build Fail Error using @react-native-community/cli
ERROR: autolinkLibrariesFromCommand: process cmd /c npx @react-native-community/cli config exited with error code: 1

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Settings file 'C:\Users\asif1\Desktop\base\android\settings.gradle' line: 3

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating settings 'android'.
> ERROR: autolinkLibrariesFromCommand: process cmd /c npx @react-native-community/cli config exited with error code: 1

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 9s.

info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details

First, when I create the minimal project using below command:
npx @react-native-community/cli@latest init AwesomeProject

Then I hit commmand either npm start or npx react-native run-android.
First time it works absolutely fine, once I add package like react navigation and I try to restart the server, i get the above build failed error
ERROR: autolinkLibrariesFromCommand


I would ensure the packages are in good condition by deleting the project cache through removing node_modules and lock files. Then I'd run npm install (or yarn install). Also, make sure you're using the latest React Native release.
npm install -g @react-native-community/cli@latest

Moreover, you may also need to clean your Gradle in the android folder.
